# Not all questions tagged with my favorite tags are highlighted

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign

As you can see in the screenshot below, although I have [linux](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linux) as a favorite tag, not all questions tagged with it are highlighted. This occurs both when looking through the questions tagged as [linux](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linux) and on the SU home page.

[image]

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're already looking at questions under a certain favorite tag, they're not all highlighted.

The highlights you see are for questions with any other favorite tag, except for [linux](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linux).

Comment: Ah, OK, that makes sense, thanks. I was under the impression that I have the same problem in the home page. I can't reproduce it at the moment so maybe I am imagining things. I'll just check over the next few days to make sure.